# Stroke alignment and placement issues

Tags: adobe-illustrator

What is the best way to add a double stroke to a set of grouped objects so that the stroke is on the inside?

When I attempt to do so, the inside stroke is greyed out.

When I try adding strokes to an unfilled rectangle and placing this on top of my grouped objects, I am struggling to get this to lined up properly, even using the x and y coordinates.

This is a seamless pattern that measures 43"x43". It needs to have a double stroke that sits inside so that the image doesn't exceed 43"x43". I'm not sure I'm explaining it correctly.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could share an image showing the problem, or what you are trying to achieve? A picture is worth a thousand words! Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely :) 

https://i.postimg.cc/jjsDXtht/screenshot.jpg

This is a seamless pattern that measures 43"x43". It needs to have a double stroke that sits inside so that the image doesn't exceed 43"x43". I'm not sure I'm explaining it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but I'll try to answer. 
One way to add a double stroke is by using the appearance panel and add a stroke and apply offset path effect to it. Set the offset to a negative number if you want it on the inside.